# javascript array displays the name of the array not the contents (gtag, purchase event)

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-analytics, gtag.js

I am trying to create a `gtag purchase` event code in a `Woocommerce Eshop` in `Thank you` page.

But when I see the code in `source` in the browser it is displaying the name of the array and not the contents.

I can see the purchases in `google dashboard` but there is no track of the items.

I can only see the total price of the purchases.

Here is my code:

```
if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ){
        $order_id = absint( get_query_var('order-received') );
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order_items = $order->get_items();
        $items_data  = []; // Initializing
        foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
            $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product_id   = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $item->get_product_id();

            //get the categories tree
            foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
                if( $term ){
                    $categories .= $term->name;
                    $categories .= '/';
                }
            }
            $categories = trim($categories, '/');
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            // Set specific data for each item in the array
            array_push($items_data, array(
                item_id          => $product->get_sku(),
                item_name        => $product->get_name(),
                item_category    => $categories,
                quantity   => $item->get_quantity(),
                price      => $item->get_subtotal(),
            ));
            $categories = '';
        }
    ?>
    <script>
        var items_data = <?=json_encode($items_data)?>;
        var my_items = [];
        
        for(var i=0; i<items_data.length; i++){ 
            var item = items_data[i]; console.log(item);
            my_items.push({
                    item_id:item.item_id,
                    item_name:item.item_name,
                    item_category:item.item_category,
                    quantity:item.quantity,
                    price:item.price
            });         
        }       
    </script>

<!-- Event snippet for Website sale conversion page -->
        <script> gtag('event', 'conversion', { 'send_to': 'AC-898s89ds/PNdsds78dsy_ds82B', 'value': '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>', 'currency': 'EUR', 'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>' }); </script> 
    <script>        
        console.log({items:my_items}); //this displays correctly the content of the array       
        
gtag('event', 'purchase', { 'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>', 'affiliation': 'eartshop.gr', 'value': '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>', 'currency': 'EUR', 'shipping': '<?php echo $order->get_shipping_total(); ?>', 'tax' : '<?php echo $order->get_total_tax();  ?>', 'items': my_items });
</script>
```

And this is what I see in the source code of `Thank you page` :

```
gtag('event', 'purchase', { 'transaction_id': '10707', 'affiliation': 'eshopdomain.com', 'value': '152.00', 'currency': 'EUR', 'shipping': '0.00', 'tax' : '29.03', 'items': my_items });
```

Comment: perhaps you will find a solution in WP stackoverflow site, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ hope it helps!

Comment: Seems like one of your tags haven't been closed. Maybe share the whole version of the file for more details?

Comment: @ManjotSinghKalsi code is very long it doesnt let me to paste it... but I double checked tags and there is nothing wrong with them...

Comment: @MarioPerez its not wordpress specific. I think its more javascript related so I guess I will have better luck here

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be optimized. Use the `woocommerce_payment_complete` and `woocommerce_thankyou` hooks to make sure the event fires every time an order is successful.

> The `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook is required for payments such
> as PayPal or credit card (Stripe or others). Customers do not always
> wait for the redirect on the site and therefore the event may not be
> activated with just the `woocommerce_thankyou` hoook.

```
// adds the Google Analytics "purchase" event to the thankyou page
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'set_google_tag_transaction_conversion_event' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'set_google_tag_transaction_conversion_event', 99, 1 );
function set_google_tag_transaction_conversion_event( $order_id ) {

    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

?>

    <!-- Event snippet for Website sale conversion page -->
    <script> gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AC-898s89ds/PNdsds78dsy_ds82B',
        'value': '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>',
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
        });
    </script> 
    <!-- Google Tag: Transaction conversion event -->
    <script>
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
        "transaction_id": "<?php echo $order_id; ?>",
        "affiliation": "eartshop.gr",
        "value": <?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>,
        "currency": "EUR",
        "tax": <?php echo $order->get_total_tax(); ?>,
        "shipping": <?php echo $order->get_shipping_total(); ?>,
        "items": [
        <?php foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_product ) {

            $product = $item_product->get_product();

            $quantity = $item_product->get_quantity();
            $subtotal_line = $item_product->get_subtotal();
            $price = $subtotal_line / $quantity;
            $product_name = $product->get_name();
            $name = str_replace( ',', '', $product_name );

            $categories = array();
            //get the categories tree
            foreach( wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
                if ( $term ) {
                    $categories[] = $term->name;
                }
            }

            if ( ! empty($categories) ) {
                $product_categories = implode( '/', $categories );
            } else {
                $product_categories = '';
            }

            ?>
            {
                "id": "<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>",
                "name": "<?php echo $name; ?>",
                "category": "<?php echo $product_categories; ?>",
                "quantity": <?php echo $quantity; ?>,
                "price": "<?php echo $price; ?>",
            },
            <?php
        } // end foreach order items
        ?>
      ]
    });

    </script>

<?php

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*